# Product with the generic fiber for a rational map between algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose we are given two algebraic varieties $X, Y$ over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{k}$, a rational map
$$\pi \colon X \mathrel{-\,}\rightarrow Y$$

and $Z$ is the generic fiber of $\pi$.

Is it always true that $X$ is birational to $Y \times Z$?
If yes, how can I prove this?
If not, by any chance is it true for the particular case, namely:
$$\pi \colon Sym^2(\mathbb{P^2}) \mathrel{-\,}\rightarrow Grass(\mathbb{P}^{1},\mathbb{P^2})$$
where $\pi$ maps two points in general positions to the line passing through them?
As far as I know, the generic fiber of $\pi$ is $Sym^2(\mathbb{P}^1)$ which is birational to $\mathbb{P}^2$ so that means there is a birational equivalence
$$Sym^2(\mathbb{P^2}) \sim \mathbb{P^2} \times \mathbb{P^2}$$

Comment: $\pi$ is rational, but I want to show that there is a birational map between $Sym^2(\mathbb{P^2})$ and $\mathbb{P^2} \times \mathbb{P^2}$ (both of dimension 4), i.e. product of $Grass(\mathbb{P}^{1},\mathbb{P^2})$ with the generic fiber of $\pi$.

Comment: Sym^2 is the quotient of the product P^2 x P^2 by $ G = \mathbb{Z}/2 $, so its function field is the invariants of the function field of P^2 x P^2. From here, can you finish it?

Comment: The product $Y \times Z$ doesn't make sense because $Y$ is a variaty over $\Bbbk$, while $Z$ is a variety over the function field of $Y$.

Comment: I think he means the 'general' fiber over a closed point, rather than the 'generic' fiber. Atleast that's what I interpreted from the example.

Comment: @CraniumClamp: This also doesn't make sense, because fibers over different general closed points may have different birational type (e.g., if these are curves of positive genus).

Comment: Thanks, I’ve understood that the questions doesn’t make sense. Although in the case of $\pi$ defined explicitly at the end of the question it is true that the generic fiber (the fiber over the generic point) is rational, and it seems that in this case a general fiber (I mean here a fiber over any closed point of some open subset of Y) is also rational (it is $Sym^2\mathbb{P}^1$), so I want to prove that $X = Sym^2(\mathbb{P}^2)$ is birational to $(\mathbb{P}^*)^2 \times Sym^2\mathbb{P}^1$ in this particular case.

Comment: @AlexeiPiskunov: The map $Sym^2(\mathbb{P}^2) \to (\mathbb{P}^*)^2$ is a Zariski locally trivial $\mathbb{P}^2$-fibration, hence $Sym^2(\mathbb{P}^2)$ is a rational variety, and hence it is birational to $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks.  I think now after some computations it is clear to me how to find explicitly for any point such an open subset that it is locally trivial for my $\pi$ (and even to write down this birational map). But I still do not understand if it is possible to realise whether a given map with isomorphic (or maybe birational) general fibers is indeed a locally trivial fibration?

Comment: @AlexeiPiskunov: This may be tricky --- as you know there are examples of morphisms which are etale locally trivial but not Zariski locally trivial.

Comment: @Sasha at least Is it correct that if $f \colon X \to Y$ is a morphism of finite type schemes over a field $\mathbb{k}$, and the generic fiber of $f$ is $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{k}(Y)}$ then $X$ is birational to $Y \times_{\mathbb{k}} \mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{k}$? $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible here.

Comment: Yes, because the general point of $X$ is the same as the general point of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\Bbbk(Y)}$ that is the spectrum of $\Bbbk(Y)(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and the same is true for the general point of $Y \times_{\Bbbk} \mathbb{P}^n_{\Bbbk}$.